# Rearrangement of Sequence $\left\{x_n\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We say that a sequence $\left\{y_n\right\}$ is a rearrangement of a sequence $\left\{x_n\right\}$ if there is a 1-1 correspondence $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall$ $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $y_n = x_{f(n)}$. Suppose $\left\{y_n\right\}$ is a rearrangement of $\left\{x_n\right\}$. Prove that $\left\{y_n\right\} \rightarrow L$ iff $\left\{x_n\right\} \rightarrow L$.

1) How do I prove this ?

Comment: What have you tried? It is pretty straightforward if you know the definitions and are not afraid to try.

Comment: I have wasted 3hrs trying this problem. I'm sorry that I don't have an IQ over 150 to solve this

Comment: @MintoP No need to be aggressive, Arnaud is simply asking for your thoughts — as, well, this site's very policy suggests you describe them to us.

Comment: "*I have wasted 3hrs trying this problem.*"  Good, then I expect that you have some of your attempts and thought process to share.

Comment: That person assumed that either I'm afraid to try or don't clearly know the proper definition. Why the hell did that guy need to be so condescending?

Comment: @MintoP *You* know you tried for 3h. How are we supposed to? Be objective: how are we supposed to tell apart your question, with no details on your efforts but asked after 3h of unfruitful attempts, from the same question from someone else, with no details on their efforts and asked immediately after reading their homework statement?

Comment: Look. I'm really in a bad mood right now. I know you guys are 1000 times more smarter than me, but than doesn't mean that I'm somewhat of a loser for not being able to solve for whole frigging 3hrs. If you want my stupid effort to this stupid problem then it would be a length of 20000 essay. I am extremely angry right now for not being able to solve this stupid problem. It also shows how mentally inferior I am.

Comment: @MintoP No, it does not. There is no mental inferiority or anything at play -- what tells you that people here haven't honed their understanding of this type of questions by solving it, or some variant of it, many times over the years? The only thing is that you should keep in mind is to try and keep your temper. If only because it's harder to find people willing to help you when you snap at them...

Comment: Minto.I consider your question interesting, tried to solve it.Not a complete beginner myself,  tried a few twists and turns until I(hopefully) got somewhere. Greetings.

Answer (score 5):

*Here is a proof using the definition of convergence with $\varepsilon$'s. It's quite straightforward, and relies on the fact that if all but finitely many elements of $(x_n)_n$ are at distance at most $\varepsilon$ from $\ell$, then you have all but finitely many elements of $(y_n)_n$ that are far from $\ell$ -- basically, the same "finitely many" elements. These elements can be spread out a bit more (by $f$), but since there are finitely many they all must be bounded by some $N$.*

1. It is sufficient to prove a single direction (convergence of $(x_n)_n$ implies convergence of $(y_n)_n$), since by symmetry this implies both directions. *(Indeed, if $(y_n)_n$ is a rearrangement of $(x_n)_n$, then $(x_n)_n$ is a rearrangement of $(y_n)_n$.)*
2. Suppose $(y_n)_n$ is a rearrangement of $(x_n)_n$, and let $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be the corresponding bijection. Suppose $(x_n)_n$ converges to some $\ell\in\mathbb{R}$.

   Fix any $\varepsilon > 0$. By assumption, there exists $n_\varepsilon\geq 1$ such that, for every $n\geq n_\varepsilon$, $\lvert x_n - \ell\rvert \leq \varepsilon$.
   Now consider $$S_\varepsilon = \{ f^{-1}(n) : n < n_\varepsilon \} = f(\{1,2,\dots,n_\varepsilon-1\})\,.\tag{1}$$
   This set is finite (it has size $n_\varepsilon-1$), and therefore it has an upper bound $N_\varepsilon$:
   $$
   \forall n \in S_\varepsilon,\qquad  n < N_\varepsilon\,. \tag{2}
   $$
   I claim that for every $n\geq N_\varepsilon$ we have $f(n) \geq n_\varepsilon$. *(Indeed, suppose by contradiction this is not the case, i.e., there exists $n^\ast \geq N_\varepsilon$ with $f(n^\ast) < n_\varepsilon$. Then $n^\ast = f^{-1}(f(n^\ast)) \in S_\varepsilon$,  contradicting $(2)$).*

   Therefore, for every $n\geq N_\varepsilon$, we have $f(n) \geq n_\varepsilon$ and therefore
   $$
   \lvert y_n - \ell\rvert = \lvert x_{f(n)} - \ell\rvert \leq \varepsilon\,.\tag{3}
   $$

   Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we showed that $(y_n)_n$ converges to $\ell$.